# HTML TextArea only show one row - Always centered in the element

Tags: html, css

Exists a property or function to always show the current row/line centered in the TextArea element; example:

[image]

I want that always shows one row (Without let know the user that exist more text up or down on the current line).
I guess that should exist a way to achieve this with CSS.

Example:

```
<textarea id="text" rows=1>Test line 1
Test line 2
Test line 3
Test line 4
</textarea>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mbv401920150/3w5Ly8bo/1/

Comment: We need some code...

Comment: There aren't any CSS rules. There may be a 3rd party javascript library, but i doubt it since no DOM elements I know of control the viewable text in a textarea box.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the property row of textarea element:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
   Your text
</textarea>
```

You can use CSS to remove the resize option at the bottom-right also like:

```
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```